# OpenGl - Where to begin?

Tags: macos, opengl, download

How do I download OpenGL for Mac? I have been using console to learn C++ for a while and want to start to learn graphics. I have searched the internet and have become more confused as to how to download OpenGL. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best place to get started http://nehe.gamedev.net/

You don't have to "download" OpenGL. You just have to link against the libraries and include the headers. To link against the libraries on Mac use the `-framework OpenGL` option with gcc. I'm not sure how to do it in xcode.

For an example project, *but a bad place to start* https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/ch4-flag, follow the fork link to jckarter.

Answer (score 1):

#### Start with these links...

- http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/gettingstarted.htm
- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/opengl_first_opengl_program.html
- http://www.edenwaith.com/products/pige/compiling/osx.php